# Converting String to Tuple Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

I'm trying to create a function for a board game that will read a position on the board as a string and convert to a coordinate that can be used in the program e.g. `"D4 => (3,3), "F2" => (5,1)"`.

So far I have this:

```
getCoord :: String -> Maybe(Int, Int)
getCoord s = 
    let alphas = "ABCDEFGH"
        coord1 = head(s)
        coord2 = tail(s)
    in ((elemIndex coord1 alphas)-1, read(head coord2)-1)
```

I'm still learning about the use of `Maybe` in Haskell and am encountering the error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe (Int, Int)’
              with actual type ‘(Maybe Int, Integer)’
• In the expression:
    ((elemIndex coord1 alphas) - 1, read (head coord2) - 1)
```

Would appreciate your help on where I might be going wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: In `Maybe (Int, Int)`, the Int tuple is the argument of `Maybe`. But `(Maybe Int, Integer)` is a tuple of `Maybe Int` and another `Int`. So if the value of the Maybe is Nothing, for the second case you still need to provide the second Int.

Comment: You'll also want to use pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail`. `getCoord [coord1, coord2] = ...`. Shorter and longer strings can be handled separately.

Comment: Further, `elemIndex` returns a `Maybe Int`, not an `Int`. You can't directly subtract 1 from that value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that `elemIndex` returns a `Maybe Int`. Since you're also trying to return a `Maybe` type, the best way to work with this is using a `do` block to perform operations inside the `Maybe` monad. This lets you use `Maybe` values as if they were normal values as long as your output will get wrapped back up in a `Maybe`. (If you need more information about how monads work, there are plenty of good answers here explaining it, and lots of other great posts across the internet.)

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.List (elemIndex)

getCoords :: String -> Maybe(Int, Int)
getCoords (coord1:coord2) = do
  let alphas = "ABCDEFGH"
  row <- elemIndex coord1 alphas
  col <- readMaybe coord2
  return (row, col - 1)
getCoords _ = Nothing
```

Note a couple other differences from your original.

1. The use of `readMaybe` instead of `read`. `readMaybe` is a special version of `read` that returns a value of type `Maybe a`. Since we're already working in a `Maybe` context, it's better to have a no-parse return `Nothing` than throw an error.
2. No `- 1` on the row. `elemIndex` already has the behavior you want, i.e. `A` will return `0`, etc.
3. Pattern match instead of `head` and `tail`. This lets you account for the case where the string is empty.
4. Extra definition to match empty list and return `Nothing`. The advantage of using a `Maybe` type is that you can return a value for errors instead of getting a Runtime error. In order to make use of that, we have to make sure we handle all of the cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This makes sense to me however I can't seem to get it to compile, i get a `parse error on input row`

Comment: Yikes. I'm missing the `do`. EDIT: fixed.